# Никак не могу вывести данные изображение из бд

Tags: php, mysql

Никак не могу вывести из таблицы строку в которой находятся изображение.

Сделал `var_dump` показывает в некоторых местах `string(0)` а в некоторых местах `string(25)`
вот и сам сайт где пытаюсь вывести изображение

http://www.firmam.biz/kariyer/

Снизу его код:

```
<?php if(!defined("TT_YAZILIM")){ 
 echo "<script>window.top.location.href = '../index.html';</script>";
 exit();
} ?> 


<style>
 .red_submit {
  width: 73px;
  height: 30PX;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #F90021;
  color: #FFF;
}

.kar_select { background:#E7E7E7; border:none;padding:5PX;}
</style> 

<div class="yeni_orta_modul">

 <div class="yeni_baslik"><?=_ISCI_SEK_1?></div>

 <div class="yeni_tek">
   <table class="tablox_v3">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Şekil</th>
        <th><?=_ILAN_DETAY_7?></th>
        <th width="19%"><?=_FIRMA_ADI?></th>
        <th width="23%"><?=_ILAN_DETAY_11?></th>
        <th width="11%"><?=_TARIH?></th>
        <th width="13%">ssss</th>
      </tr>

      <?php
      require_once 'lib/sayfalama.class.php';
      $kosul = ' ';
      $kat=intval($_GET['kat']);
      $poz=intval($_GET['poz']);
      $sekil=intval($_GET['sekil']);
      $cins=intval($_GET['cins']);
      $egitim=intval($_GET['egitim']);
      $ttsehir=intval($_GET['ttsehir']);
      $ttilce=intval($_GET['ttilce']);
      $kelimekar=temizle($_GET['kelimekar']);


      if($kat>'' and $kat!=0){ $kosul = $kosul . ' and kariyer.kat='.$kat.' '; }
      if($poz>'' and $poz!=0){ $kosul = $kosul . ' and kariyer.pozisyon='.$poz.' '; }
      if($sekil>'' and $sekil!=0){ $kosul = $kosul . ' and kariyer.sekil='.$sekil.' '; }
      if($cins>'' and $cins!=0){ $kosul = $kosul . ' and kariyer.cins='.$cins.' '; }
      if($egitim>'' and $egitim!=0){ $kosul = $kosul . ' and kariyer.egitim='.$egitim.' '; }
      if($ttsehir>'' and $ttsehir!=0){ $kosul = $kosul . ' and kariyer.sehir='.$ttsehir.' '; }
      if($ttilce>'' and $ttilce!=0){ $kosul = $kosul . ' and kariyer.ilce='.$ttilce.' '; }
      if(isset($kelimekar)) { if($kelimekar!=_ARANACAK ){ $kosul = $kosul . ' and kariyer.baslik like \'%'.$kelimekar.'%\''; } }

      $db_count=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT kariyer.id FROM kariyer inner join firma on firma.id=kariyer.fid left join ustkat on ustkat.ust_id=kariyer.kat left join pozisyon on pozisyon.pid=kariyer.pozisyon  where 1 ".$kosul." and  firma.onay=1 and kariyer.onay=1   "));
      $pages = new Paginator;
      $pages->items_total = $db_count;
      $pages->mid_range = 3;
      $pages->default_ipp = $rowtt['liste_sayisi'];
      $pages->paginate();
      $ilksorgu="SELECT kariyer.id, kariyer.ishresim, kariyer.baslik, kariyer.detay, kariyer.ilan_bas_tarih, firma.adi, kariyer.fid, kariyer.kat, ustkat.ust_adi FROM kariyer inner join firma on firma.id=kariyer.fid  left join ustkat on ustkat.ust_id=kariyer.kat  left join pozisyon on pozisyon.pid=kariyer.pozisyon where 1 ".$kosul."     and firma.onay=1 and kariyer.onay=1  order by kariyer.ilan_bas_tarih desc $pages->limit";
      $sql=mysql_query($ilksorgu) or die(mysql_error());



      while($ilan=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
       {?>

     <tr>
      <td><img src="/<?php var_dump($ilan['ishresim']); ?>" width="60" height="45" alt=""/> </td>
      <td> <a title="<?php echo $ilan['baslik']; ?>" href="kariyer/eleman-ilanlari/<?php echo seo($ilan['baslik']) ;?>_<?php echo $ilan['id']; ?>.html" ><?php echo tt_kes($ilan['baslik'],40); ?></a></td>
      <td> <?php echo tt_kes($ilan['adi'],20); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo tt_kes($ilan['ust_adi'],20); ?></td>
      <td><?php var_dump ($ilan); ?></td>
      <td>
        <a title="<?php echo $ilan['baslik']; ?>" href="kariyer/eleman-ilanlari/<?php echo seo($ilan['baslik']) ;?>_<?php echo $ilan['id']; ?>.html" >
          <img src="images/v3/basvur.png" width="95" height="25" alt="Detaylar" />
        </a>
        <?php include("include/popbireygir-form.php"); ?>

        <?php }?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


</div>
</div>


<?php
echo "<div class='sayfalama_kutu'>";
echo $pages->display_pages();
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ место того чтобы добавиться в таблицу в посте оно создавала новую таблицу для каждого изображение